# Virtual Keyboard on Ipad make the input[type=range] slider thumb disappear

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, slider, mobile-safari

I am currently developing a web site for an iPad Air and Firefox, with bootstrap.

In a page, I have an input type=number that allows the user to change the value of the input type=range. I have set the onkeypress event of my input type=number to force the blur() when the ENTER key is pressed.

> function onkeyPressFunction(){
>
> ```
>     var isEnter = charCode == 13;
>
>     if (isEnter)
>        {
>            document.activeElement.blur();
>        }
> ```
>
> }

The problem is that on Ipad, when I press the go button on the virtual keyboard, the thumb of the slider disappears.

I have tested it on Firefox and I do not have this problem.

Comment: I found that the problem was a render problem. When I zoom in and then zoom out, the thumb of the slider reappear.

Comment: Please add that as an answer and provide the details of the solution so people will learn from it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was a render problem. When I zoom in and then zoom out, the thumb of the slider reappear.